# configurar wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

estoy intentando subir una pagina hecha en wordpress a un host pero al momento de modificar en ajustes deje la instalacion de wordpress en el servidor y la url se la deje en el localhost por error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
asi como en la imagen,necesito saber en que archivo se encuentra esa configuracion

Comment: cual es el error  que te da?, cual es el host?

Comment: Esa información no se encuentra en ningún archivo, sino en la base de datos. Si quieres cambiarla por la URL real recomiendo que lo hagas desde el panel, si te lo permite. Y si no, que lo cambies directamente en la base de datos, pues hay varias formas de definir la URL del sitio, pero lo mejor es actualizarla en la base de datos. Para más info puedes ver [la documentación de WP](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

Comment: no me permitía entrar al panel pero me de la  base de datos si me sirvió, muchas gracias ya quedó

Answer (score 0):

Eso lo encuentras en la base de datos dentro de la tabla wp-options > siteurl y home, en tu editor de base de datos o por medio de comando asignas la url o de lo contrario inserta en tu functions.php:

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

O en tu wp-config:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```